# USB Mouse not recognized

Tags: 12.04, drivers, usb, mouse

Just installed Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit through wubi on my Asus A52F. Now I can't get my usb mouse working. I made sure to update the `xserver-xorg-input-mouse` driver through software center, trackpad is working fine

```
jesse@ubuntu:~$ xsetpointer -l | grep Pointer
2: "Virtual core pointer"   [XPointer]
4: "Virtual core XTEST pointer" [XExtensionPointer]
12: "ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad"  [XExtensionPointer]
```

Comment: Can you confirm the module `psmouse` is loaded? Try running `sudo modprobe psmouse` to see if this solves your problem, although it should be already loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a troubleshooting step, have you tried this both with "Legacy USB support" turned on, and off, in your computer's BIOS?

Answer (score 1):

It took turning off legacy support that seems to fix it for now. Unfortunately the keyboard isn't recognized during boot, so the fix is a pain in the tail.